# How does neo4j traverse a graph during Query execution

Tags: neo4j

How exactly does neo4j traverse a graph during query execution. Is it sub-graph matching or does it do any similarity search. I am not too familiar with neo4j, but i am trying to create a Query formulation framework for neo4j and would like to know how a is query matched in the graph (database).

Any help,advice or direction would be helpful.

Comment: Check out the free online book http://neo4j.com/books/graph-databases/ it goes into depth on how Cypher traverses graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated, Neo4j takes your Cypher query as a meta-description of what you want and depending on statistics, available indexes etc. it uses a combination of operations to execute the query.

Potential operations are lookups of nodes, expand, expand-into (between two nodes), hash-join, apply and semi-apply.

There is a introductory blog post: http://neo4j.com/blog/introducing-new-cypher-query-optimizer/

And a manual section: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/execution-plans.html

Starting from Neo4j 2.3 those operations will be partially compile to Java Bytecode allowing for fast execution.